# SQL запрос в зависимости от нажатого пункта

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

У меня есть несколько (15) пунктов с названиями заданий на выбор в одном столбике и кнопка "Принять" в другом. Как сделать так, чтобы "принималась" пользователем именно выбранное задание? Есть скрипт с формой в профиле, только в нём вписывается название задания, а не выбирается наглядно само задание. Вот картинка: [image: доступные задания и кнопка принять]

Скрипт принятия заданий:

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
session_start();
//include "phpinjson.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $susername = $_SESSION["username"];
    //запрос который считает, сколько у пользователя принятых заданий
    $countquery = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE takenby = '$susername' AND place=1";
    //принятие задания - в значения "кем взято" вписывается ник вошедшего юзера, в "имя" - вписанное название задания. место 0 - доступные задания, место 1 - взятые
    $query = "UPDATE tasks SET takenby='$susername', place=1 WHERE name='$name' AND place=0";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $countquery);
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if (mysqli_query($link, $query) && $row_cnt < 3) {
            echo "Задача взята.";
            header("Refresh: 2;url=user.php");
        } else {
            echo "Ошибка: возможно, введено неправильное название задачи или достигнут максимум активных заданий. " . " :-" . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: @DrMcSheen в вопросе написано - "Как сделать так, чтобы "принималось" пользователем именно выбранное задание?", я не понимаю, как это сделать

Comment: здесь нужно начать с рассмотрения отправки формы. как выбирается задание и какие данные передаются на сервер

Comment: Не нужно ничего менять. Любой школьник, который будет пользваться этим сайтом, и так запишет любое значение в базу данных через этот код.